# convert json string to csv using javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I have seen some of the posts for converting json to csv
for example 'http://jsfiddle.net/FLR4v/'.
I could not make them to convert this json to csv .

Here is my code (this works well but does not work with commented out var json3 below)

```
 <html>
    <head>
    <title>JSON to CSV</title>
    <script src="json.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    //var json3 = { "inp1:val1": { "data": [ [ 1378267200000, 0.0743 ], [ 1378270800000, 0.1787 ] ] }}
    var json3 = { "data": [ [ 1378267200000, 0.0743 ], [ 1378270800000, 0.1787 ], ] }
    DownloadJSON2CSV(json3.data);

    function DownloadJSON2CSV(objArray)
    {
        var array = typeof objArray != 'object' ? JSON.parse(objArray) : objArray;

        var str = '';

        for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            var line = '';

            for (var index in array[i]) {
                line += array[i][index] + ',';
            }

            // Here is an example where you would wrap the values in double quotes
            // for (var index in array[i]) {
            //    line += '"' + array[i][index] + '",';
            // }

            line.slice(0,line.Length-1); 

            str += line + '\r\n';
        }
        window.open( "data:text/csv;charset=utf-8," + escape(str))
    }

    </script>

   </head>
   <body>
    <h1>This page does nothing....</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

The above code works ok.
  What I need is the above needs to work with the below

```
var json3 = { "inp1:val1": { "data": [ [ 1378267200000, 0.0743 ], [ 1378270800000, 0.1787 ] ] }}
```

### Thanks for your help

Comment: Possibly because you don't have any labels for your values. What have you tried?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please click "edit" to add an example of your desired output to your question. Also, do you have that input JSON in a variable, or...? (And please, can't you give us a shorter sample input? Surely you only needed to include three or four of the inner arrays to make your point.)

Comment: That jsfiddle doesn't work properly anyway. It needs underscore.js.

Comment: That's not a valid JSON. Check with http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: Typo fixed. It is a valid jason now. Still problem exists. It is a shorter input now for ease of reading.
Thanks

Comment: can some one look into this please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You still haven't explained clearly what your desired output is ("CSV" is too vague, especially when your original jsfiddle produced *semicolon* separated output).

But you do seem to be saying that your code works if you take this object:

```
    var json3 = { "data": [ [ 1378267200000, 0.0743 ], [ 1378270800000, 0.1787 ], ] }
```

...as input to your function as follows:

```
DownloadJSON2CSV(json3.data);
```

But now you want to deal with an input object that has a slightly different structure, essentially the same thing but with an extra "wrapping" layer around your original structure:

```
var json3 = { "inp1:val1": { "data": [ [ 1378267200000, 0.0743 ], [ 1378270800000, 0.1787 ] ] }}
```

**If I've summed up your question accurately, here's what you need:**

```
DownloadJSON2CSV(json3["inp1:val1"].data);
```

This calls your function passing the array of arrays referenced by the "data" property of the object referenced by the "inp1:val1" property of the outermost object.

(Note that what you are calling "json" is not json at all, it is an object that happens to be created using JS's object literal syntax.)

Homework for you: read the MDN article [Working With Objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects).